# Estimate of $|(f*g)(x)-f(x)|$ where $g$ is approximation to the identity

Tags: analysis, convolution

Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous with compact support $[0,1]$. Assume $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then let $0< \delta <1$ s.t.
$$
 \forall x,y \in \mathbb R: |x-y| < \delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| <\epsilon
$$ The existence of such a $\delta > 0$ I have already proven. Now let $g:[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be an $(\delta,\epsilon)$-approximation to the identity. I want to show that for all $x \in [0,1]$ we have
$$
 |(f*g)(x)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon(3M +2\delta)
$$ But I don't get the right bound. Here is what I did:

Let $x \in [0,1]$. Then

\begin{align}
   |(f*g)(x)-f(x)|& = \left | \int_{-1}^1 f(x-y)g(y) dy - \int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(y) dy \right| \\
   & = \left | \int_{-1}^1 g(y)(f(x-y)-f(x)) dy \right |
   \\
   &\leq \left | \int_{-\delta}^\delta (f(x-y)-f(x))g(y) dy \right | + \left | \int_{|x| \geq \delta} (f(x-y)-f(x))g(y) dy \right | \\
   &\leq  \int_{-\delta}^\delta \epsilon |g(y)| dy  +  \int_{|x| \geq \delta} 2M |g(y)| dy \\
   &\leq \epsilon + 2M \int_{|x| \geq \delta} \epsilon dy \\
   &\leq \epsilon + 2M \cdot 2(1-\delta) \epsilon \\
   &= \epsilon(1+4M(1-\delta)) = \epsilon(1+4M - 4M\delta)
  \end{align} Where is the mistake ? I used in the first line that $\int_{[-1,1]} g = 1$ further the property given in the question and the $|x| \geq \delta \rightarrow |g(x)| \leq \epsilon$.

Comment: I don't see any problems with your reasoning. We would be able to write somewhat finer estimations if we had, for example, such properties as $g\ge 0$, $f\in\mathcal C^2$ and $g$ is even. Then with Poincare's inequality the estimation on the first integral in terms of $M,\,\delta,\,\epsilon$ would be finer.

Comment: Indeed, $g \geq 0$ by definition of an approximation to the identity. Further $g$ is continuous with support $[-1,1]$.

Comment: By the way: This is from Tao Analysis II Ex. 14.8.6 (b).

Comment: Can you state the definition for an $(\epsilon,\delta)$ approximation to the identity? It might not be a standard terminology yet.

Comment: Let $\epsilon >0$ and $0 < \delta < 1$. Then $g:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is said to be and $(\epsilon,\delta)$-approximation to the identity if $g$ is supported on $[-1,1]$ and $g \geq 0$ on $[-1,1]$, $g$ is continuous and $\int_{\mathbb R} g = 1$, $|g(x)| \leq \epsilon$ if $\delta \leq |x| \leq 1$.

Comment: But you ended with a bound which is a multiple of $\epsilon$. Most times that's enough, isn't it this case?

Comment: Yes. But I wondered how Tao came to this bound :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not surprised that you don't manage to show

$$\lvert (f \ast g)(x) - f(x)\rvert \leqslant \epsilon(3M + 2\delta)$$

under the given hypotheses.

**Because in general, it does not hold.**

If such an estimate would hold for all $(\epsilon,\delta)$-approximations of the identity, it would, by taking limits, also hold for the Dirac measures located in $z \in [-\delta,\, \delta]$, and that would mean you'd have

$$\sup_{\lvert y\rvert \leqslant \delta} \lvert f(x-y) - f(x)\rvert \leqslant \epsilon(3M+2\delta).$$

When $\delta$ is chosen as large as possible for the given $\epsilon$, the left hand side becomes $\epsilon$ for some $x$, and that would imply $3M + 2\delta \geqslant 1$. But we can easily construct examples where that does not hold.

If, in your computation, you use the fact that $f(x-y) = 0$ when $x \leqslant y \leqslant 1$ or $-1 \leqslant y \leqslant x-1$, so on these intervals you can estimate $\lvert f(x-y)-f(x)\rvert$ by $M$ instead of $2M$, you get an estimate

$$\lvert (f\ast g)(x) - f(x)\rvert \leqslant \epsilon(1+3M - 2M\delta),$$

which is closer to the stated goal.